# Running tests against EF no data returned. Is this right? (beginner)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm writing my first unit tests and not mocking (that's my next learning process). Web app, mvc, EF6, vs2015, ms test units.

If I call any method to fill a dataset from my controllers, it fills with data.
If I call the same methods from a test unit, they return empty datasets.
Is this what I should expect? (Sorry, I googled the question first, but couldn't find an answer)

Comment: Please post your code (from your Controllers and nunit tests)

Comment: Are you using a connection string located in your config file, and are your tests located in a different project?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a connection string that's located in the App.config of your project then you must duplicate this in the test project also.

A more ideal way to do this is have the code require a connection string that's provided by the caller as this allows you to test what happens with an invalid connection string.

```
public EntityName(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
}
```